Questions on Khovanskii Theorem - Fewnomials ( section 1.4)
I'm studying a paper on Abel piecewise linear ODE and came across the following Theorem due to Khovanskii (Fewnomials, sec 1.4):
Theorem (Khovanskii): Let $P_1 =... = P_n = 0$ be a system of n equations with n real unknowns $x = x_1 , ... , x_n$, where $P_i$ is a polynomial of degree m, in $n + k + 2\rho$  real variables $x, y_1,...,y_k,u_1 ...,u_p, v1,...,v_p$, where $y_j = \exp\langle a_j,x\rangle$, $j = 1, ... , k$ and $u_q =  \sin\langle b_q,x\rangle$. $v_q =\cos \langle b_q,x\rangle$, $q = 1, ... , \rho$. Then the number of nonsingular solutions of this system in theregion bounded by the inequalities $|\langle b_q,x\rangle| < x/2$,  $q = 1, ... , \rho$, is finite and less than
$$m_1\dotso m_n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n m_i+\rho+1  \right)^{\rho+k}2^{\rho+(\rho+k)(\rho+k-1)/2} $$
I understand that the general idea is to estimate an upper bound for the number of solutions of some system. However, I'm having some trouble understanding the details of the proof. What does $\exp\langle a_j,x\rangle, \sin\langle b_q,x\rangle, \cos \langle b_q,x\rangle$ mean? Is $\langle,\rangle$ supposed to be the usual notation of inner product?
Reference:
Hilbert Number for a Family of Piecewise Nonautonomous
Equations (Theorem 2.9 on page 10 from the pdf)

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

I'm familiar with writing in latex, pardon my laziness, I didn't think it would compromise the understanding of the question since it's not a long sentence. Anyways, I've edited it, thanks for the comment.

Please add a link to the paper. Also, please write the theorem down with MathJax. Images are bad for conveying mathematical content (for example, bad for searching, and bad for accessibility). See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121

just added it, thanks for the suggestion
